# precise definition of limit at infinity

Tags: calculus

I am supposed to prove this limit using the Precise Definition of limit.
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{3x+2}{2x+3}=\frac32$$

Given $\epsilon>0$, there is a number $N$ such that $x>N$ implies that \begin{eqnarray}
\left|\frac{3x+2}{2x+3}-{3/2}\right| &< & \epsilon, \\
\implies \left|\frac{2(3x+2)-3(2x+3)}{2(2x+3)}\right| &<& \epsilon, \\
\implies \left|\frac{-5}{2(2x+3)}\right| &<& \epsilon.
\end{eqnarray}

How do I proceed from here, what should my $N$ be?

Comment: Solve for $x$. $\;$

Comment: You know that $\frac{-5}{2(2x+3)}$ is negative for positive $x$, which helps you get away with the absolute value signs.

Comment: For positive $x$ the bottom is bigger than $x$, so $N$ any integer greater than $\frac{5}{\epsilon}$ will do, say $\left\lceil \frac{5}{\epsilon}\right\rceil$. Of course we can get away with a cheaper $N$, but it's not worth bothering to do so for the proof.

Comment: I want to underline @AndréNicolas's point. At this stage, put an upper bound on the expression to make it easy to work with. All you need to do is find *an* $N$ given $\epsilon$, not the *best* $N$ given $\epsilon$. So you might as well make that choice of $N$ as easy as possible. This is also in the spirit of other bounds and calculations you will do in the courses after this one.

Comment: The way you write about this suggests that you haven't made the effort to write down your definition of a limit (of a function) and apply it to your given setup. *Do that*, before you try to go through the details of a supposed proof. So, **1.** Write down the definition of a limit. **2.** Write down the definition of a limit for a function (you're dealing with that here); note that the sequence-based definition makes most sense here **3.** Solve it yourself. It's very easy when you are working with the definition properly.

Answer (score 2):

For such problems you often need to simplify your inequalities as much as possible. Our goal is to constrain the values of $x$ in a certain manner (namely keeping $x$ greater than an appropriate positive $N$) such that the inequality $$\left|\frac{3x+2}{2x+3}-\frac{3}{2}\right|<\epsilon \tag{1}$$ is satisfied. The last inequality is equivalent to $$\left|\frac{5}{2(2x+3)}\right|<\epsilon $$ If $x>0$ (this is our first constraint on $x$) then the above is equivalent to $$\frac{5}{4x+6}<\epsilon\tag{2}$$ Next note the obvious inequality $$\frac{5}{4x+6}<\frac{5}{x}$$ and hence if we ensure that $5/x<\epsilon$ our desired inequality $(2)$ will automatically be satisfied (this step is the part which one must understand clearly and it is here that we make a great and obvious simplification of our inequalities involved). And therefore our goal is achieved by having $x>5/\epsilon$ (this is our second constraint on $x$). Thus we can see that it is sufficient to choose $N=5/\epsilon$ and then $x>N$ will ensure that the desired inequality $(1)$ will be satisfied.

Problems based on the $\epsilon, \delta$ (or $\epsilon, N$) definition of limit are *not supposed to be an exercise in solving inequalities to get something like $x>N$ from the the starting inequality $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon$ via algebraic manipulation*. Thinking these problems as algebraic manipulation of inequalities misses the whole point of the definition of limit.

Comment: To the Proposer: We do not need to find the least possible $N$ for a given  positive $\epsilon$, so a great amount of simplification is available. E.g.,  observe that when $x>0$ we have $2x+3>2x>0 $ and hence $|-5/[2(2x+3)]\;|=5/[2(2x+3)\;]$ $<5/[2(2x)]=5/4x<2/x.$  So it is sufficient to take $N=2/\epsilon.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Your simplification involves a bit more steps, but is a continuation of what OP did and perhaps may be more helpful to OP.

Comment: Thank you.....Many students make it more difficult by getting caught up in details, especially algebraic details. I wanted to emphasize that precision is often unnecessary, for example when any sufficiently large N will serve the purpose at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Take $$N= \frac{5}{4\epsilon}-\frac32$$
And then proceed by
$$x>N$$
Put value of $N$ and then solve.

Comment: This doesn't explain how one find the value of $N$.

Comment: I have read that we can also guess the value of N according to the que. but it should imply
for
$$\epsilon$$>0 
$$x>N$$
and I guessed by soving the eq $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{5}{2(2x+3)}>\epsilon$$
for

Answer (score 0):

As the LHS of the last inequality is a decreasing function, you can take any value of $N$ that satisfies it.

$$\frac{5}{2(2N+3)}<\epsilon,$$

then

$$2N+3>\frac{5}{2\epsilon},$$

$$N>\frac12\left(\frac{5}{2\epsilon}-3\right).$$

---

For such problems, gross estimates are sufficient.

$$\frac{5}{2(2N+3)}<\frac{5}{4N}<\frac2N<\epsilon,$$ and you can take $\dfrac2\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

One more attempt:

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb  N} \rightarrow \infty$ :

For every $K \in$  $\mathbb R$ there exists a   $n_0$ such that for $n \ge n_0$   $x_n \ge K$.

$ \epsilon \gt 0$ given.

Choose $K > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$, and $n \ge n_0$  then:

$|\frac{(3x_n + 2)}{(2x_n + 3)} - \frac{3}{2}|$ =

$|\frac{ -5}{2(2x_n +3)}| \lt \frac{5}{4x_n} \lt \frac{2}{x_n} \le \frac{2}{K} \lt \epsilon$.